# How can I test the pages API without getting my app reviewed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am in the process of developing an analytics platform which pulls in stats for a business from Yelp, Google, FB and their own POS systems.

I would like to just get the review count, rating and page likes for various pages to test this (all public pages).

From reading the docs It doesn't seem like I need permission from each page owner to do this but I need "Page Public Content Access". In order to do so I have to take a video of me using it in my app... how am I supposed to do this when I can't develop it?

I saw other similar questions and nothing seems to work for me. I did try my own access token and one of the pages I own and that doesn't return me the same error but just empty data all the time...

So I am caught in a loop right now unable to progress.

Hopefully someone can help me shed some light on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you cannot get reviews/ratings if you don´t manage the page. you were never able to do that. and you can develop an app with the data of your own page before sending it in for review. if it returns empty data for your own pages, you are doing it wrong. hard to say what exactly you did wrong, you need to add more details to your question. could be that you are using a user token, could be missing permissions, ...

Comment: @luschn ah OK I guess I misunderstood the docs, I see now re-reading them. Somehow it works now, I was literally doing exactly the same thing yesterday, just using the graph API explorer so I am not sure exactly what changed... it is a new page not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Appreciate your quick response though apologies this turned out to probably be a PICNIC error though!